# how to OnClick button in LinerLayout to Retreieve particular's row value?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Following is my code.I use spring JSON restful web service to retrieve list of data and display at ADT.Display mulriple rows of data works fine ^_^.

**My question is,how do I retrieve particular item row's value on user click button row?**

```
|  Id   | Description | Button  |
|  2    | iPhone 5    |(Submit) |
|  3    | Samsung Tab |(Submit) |
```

Lets say user click on "submit" button on 2nd row, so that system would know id is 3.

Hope someone advice

Regards

```
public class MyMainActivity extends ListActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(){...}

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        new HttpRequestTask().execute();

    }

    public void pickActions(View v){

    }

    private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ArrayList<ItemDetail>>{
        protected ArrayList<ItemDetail> doInBackground(Void... params){

            final String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/restdata";
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            List<ItemDetail> resultList = Arrays.asList(restTemplate.getForObject(url, ItemDetail[].class));
            ArrayList<ItemDetail> list = new ArrayList<ItemDetail>();
            if(resultList.size()>0){
                for(int i=0;i<resultList.size();i++){
                    ItemDetail itemDetail = resultList.get(i);                  
                    list.add(itemDetail);

                }
            }

            return list;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ItemDetail> list) {
         m_adapter = new TheArrayAdapter(MyMainActivity .this,list);
        setListAdapter(m_adapter);
        }

    }

}
```

the adapter

```
public class TheArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemDetail>{
    private ArrayList<ItemDetail> objects;
    private String currentSku;

    public TheArrayAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<ItemDetail> objects){
         super(context,R.layout.activity_main_list,objects);
         the.objects = objects;
    }

    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
        View v = convertView;

        //....//
        ItemDetail i = objects.get(position);

        if(i!=null){
            TextView itemId= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemId)
            Button btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.submitButton)

            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //new ListFruitActivity().pickActions(v);
        //String s = currentsku;
        v.getId();
        System.out.println("selected: "+v.getId());
        }
    });


        }



    }
}
```

the main activity xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:clickable="true"
    ....>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemId"
    ....>
</TextView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submitButton"
    android:onClick="pickActions"
    android:clickable="true"
    ..../>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it is pretty unclear what you are asking. please try to reformulate your question.

Comment: does my question clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is to use **setTag**  . You can set the item id on the button using setTag like this

```
Button btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.submitButton)
btn.setTag(id);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // retrieve the button item id
     int itemId = (Integer)v.getTag();
     // now you have the id, do your other stuff based not the id here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have position parameter in the getview meyhod which will tell you which row you are clicking

```
public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
        View v = convertView;

        //....//
        ItemDetail i = objects.get(position);

        if(i!=null){
            TextView itemId= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemId)
            Button btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.submitButton)

            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("selected: "+position);
        }
    });


        }
```